# corona images scaling in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, iphone, lua, coronasdk

Whats going wrong here? I test my game on corona simulator and it works great on all devices. I make a build of the game and play it on iPhone 5 and it doesn't scale. High res images are swapped being swapped because I made slight changes to each just to be sure, each image was x2.

Why is this happening? why is corona simulator scaling nicely and on device it isn't?

My background Image (one of many other images not scaling to full length of iphone5)

```
BG = display.newImageRect("images/bgNight.png", 570,360)
BG.anchorX = 0.5;
BG.anchorY = 0.5;
BG.x = display.contentCenterX
BG.y = display.contentCenterY
BG.alpha = 1
group:insert(BG)
```

Config.lua

```
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth

application =
{
   content =
   {
        width = aspectRatio > 1.5 and 320 or math.ceil(480 / aspectRatio),
        height = aspectRatio < 1.5 and 480 or math.ceil(320 * aspectRatio),
        scale = "letterbox",
        fps = 60,
        imageSuffix =
        {
            ["@2x"] = 1.5,
        },
  },
}
```

build.settings.lua

```
settings = {    
    orientation = {
         default = "landscapeRight",
         supported = { "landscapeRight", "landscapeLeft"}
    },
    iphone = {
        plist = {
            UIStatusBarHidden = true,           
            UIAppFonts = { 
                        "Jazz Zebra.ttf",
                         }  
        }
    },
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "High res images are swapped"? also, does it work on any other device than iphone5?

Comment: Sorry I just meant that with the config.lua the @2x.png files were loaded to cover the larger screens but still end up being the size of an iphone 3G and 4 screen size. Whereas on simulator they load and cover the full screen for iphone 5. I only have an iphone 4 and 5 to test with. It works normal on iphone 4 but I'll try again.

Comment: Look at http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html#TOC In Lauch images there is an important section, with a warning about include the iPhone 5 launch image Default-568h@2x.png to activate the "tall" mode.

Comment: Check my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651591/what-sizes-of-images-do-i-need-for-background-and-sprites-in-corona-to-support-a/15263747#15263747

Comment: Thanks guys for the the help here, I'll try your suggestions and report back.

Comment: Thanks guys, its now working properly. Turns out I needed the Launch image in my project folder. Thanks for the assistance :)

Comment: Throw it in as an aswer to your own question, that way when people search for it they will be able to find the solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this config and try

```
application = 
 {
 content = 
  { 
    width = 640 * (display.pixelHeight/display.pixelWidth>1.5 and 1 or  1.5/(display.pixelHeight/display.pixelWidth)),
    height = 960 * (display.pixelHeight/display.pixelWidth<1.5 and 1 or (display.pixelHeight/display.pixelWidth)/1.5),
    scale = "letterbox",
    -- xAlign = "center",
    -- yAlign = "center",
    imageSuffix =
    {
        ["@2x"] = 2,
        ["@4x"] = 3.0,
    },
   },
   }
```

BG.x = display.contentWidth/2
BG.y = display.contentHeight/2